# Passing value from codebehind with asyncupload after complete?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, controls, toolkit

I'm trying to pass a value to a feedbacklabel after an asynch upload.

```
Protected Sub FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName)
        AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("tmp/") + filename)

        lblFeedback.Text = "File uploaded. Processing information"

        'Get a StreamReader class that can be used to read the file

        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
        objStreamReader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("tmp/") + filename)

        While objStreamReader.Peek <> -1
            lblFeedback.Text += objStreamReader.ReadLine()

        End While
        objStreamReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

The thing is I need to display how many rows have been uploaded in the database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add at the end of `FileUploadComplete` procedure following method call (I hope you can translate it from C# to VB):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "feedback", string.Format("top.$get('{0}').innerText = '{1}'", lblFeedback.ClientID, lblFeedback.Text), true);
```